# Drupal - Bootstrap4 blocking upload of file in Webform

Tags: file, drupal, drupal-webform

I have a problem trying to upload a file in my Drupal Webform. I get the following error **"An unrecoverable error has occurred. The transferred file exceeds the maximum file size (250 MB) allowed by the server."** I tried to change the maximum file size on the server and in the Webform settings, in order to accept smaller file sizes (9 Kb), but the file always returns an error.

The error comes from the bootstrap4 theme installed on Drupal, and only appears when I add a Twig template to the Webform. If no template is in place, the error doesn't appear and the file is added to the form.